# Thermocouple vs Thermostat

Tags: cooling-system, heat, temperature, thermostat, thermodynamics

Why don't modern engines use a thermocouple (electronic temperature sensor) instead of a (wax element) thermostat?

Comment: This question reminds me of the ones like "why don't cars use cameras instead of a rear view mirror".  Some things just work and work very well even tho the tech might seem dated.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I see your correlation. It's not really the same thing though.

Answer (score 4):

A thermocouple merely generates voltage according to the temperature, while an automotive thermostat is basically an autonomous temperature sensitive coolant valve. You can't replace a thermostat with a thermocouple because their functions are completely different. You could replace a coolant sensor with a thermocouple, but resistive sensors are more convenient to use in this case.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the prevalence of wax-element thermostats as opposed to electric thermostats

Comment: @Zaid Might be, but it doesn't have much to do with thermocouples. I'll update the answer when it becomes more clear.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Good answer; but of course, a thermocouple could actuate a variable response from a separate component (coolant valve).

Comment: @Zaid Not quite, I got the idea when troubleshooting a gas hot water heater (yes, even though it had an (electric/electronic?) thermostat as well).. but do feel free to expand on your idea, if you like. It's quite relevant.

Comment: @tjt263 as in, a coolant valve whose position depends on the temperature sensed by the thermocouple? But what would be the point of the thermocouple then, the coolant temperature sensor already senses temperature. Using an electronically controlled coolant valve adds unnecessary complication as well.

Comment: The point of the thermocouple as always would be to sense the temp. Im talking about a voltage controlled switch, I guess. Similar to a variable resistor. Or you might even just tap into the *<coolant temperature sensor>* instead. I'm just speculating. I guess the real answer is;:A wax thermostat just works and it works well; It has less dependencies, and less physical moving parts.

Comment: @Zaid Actually: In retrospect, maybe you were right.

Comment: @tjt263 Oh, the point is that the switch would be controlled directly by the thermocouple? In that case you're right, it's doable, but not cheaper or more reliable than the good ol' wax thermostat.